# Roslyn Analyzer not working with more than one file in project

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

Okay, I have this analyzer running in a project :

```
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class GipAnalyzerAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "TestAnalyzer";

    private static readonly string Title = "Using directive";
    private static readonly string MessageFormat = "Please do not use this namespace in that solution.";
    private static readonly string Description = "Some namespace should not be used in certain projects";
    private const string Category = "Using Directives";

    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
         context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSyntax, SyntaxKind.UsingDirective);
    }

    private void AnalyzeSyntax(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext obj)
    {

        var directive = (UsingDirectiveSyntax) obj.Node;
        var qualifiedName = directive.Name;
        var qualifiedNameString = qualifiedName.ToFullString();

        if (qualifiedNameString.StartsWith("Name.Space.1") ||
            qualifiedNameString.StartsWith("Name.Space.2"))
        {
            // produce a diagnostic.
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, qualifiedName.GetLocation(), qualifiedName);
            obj.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }

}
```

Everything is working well until there is more than one file in the project.
With two files in the project for example, the diagnostic is properly identified but the diagnostic is not shown.

Any idea ?